# How can I get the speed of Vehicle SUMO

Tags: networking, omnet++, simulator, veins, sumo

I've run SUMO 0.30.0 , with Veins 5.0 and omnetpp 4.7
I was editing in the file veins-5.0\src\veins\modules\application\ieee80211p\DemoBaseAppLayer.cc

```
void DemoBaseApplLayer::handleLowerMsg(cMessage* msg)
{
    
    BaseFrame1609_4* wsm = dynamic_cast<BaseFrame1609_4*>(msg);
    ASSERT(wsm);
double myspeed = mobility->getSpeed(); 
if (myspeed < 16 ) {
    if (DemoSafetyMessage* bsm = dynamic_cast<DemoSafetyMessage*>(wsm)) {
        receivedBSMs++;
        onBSM(bsm);
    }
    else if (DemoServiceAdvertisment* wsa = dynamic_cast<DemoServiceAdvertisment*>(wsm)) {
        receivedWSAs++;
        onWSA(wsa);
    }
    else {
        receivedWSMs++;
        onWSM(wsm);
    }
}
    delete (msg);
}
```

to get Vehicles speeds, but it back with an error. Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

As you did not include what error you are seeing and when you are seeing this error, I am guessing that your simulation builds fine, but crashes when run.

I would further guess that `mobility` is set to a `nullptr` because your code runs on a node that is not mobile (e.g., a Road Side Unit, RSU).

Comment: the error is "Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741819"